# Linkedin Request Token failed oauth_acceptable_timestamps

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm getting the following error while calling for LinkedIn Request Token API call using PHP.

```
["oauth_problem"]=> string(17) "timestamp_refused" ["oauth_acceptable_timestamps"]=> string(15) "1452192042+-900" }
```

What do I need to do to fix this problem?